# where is the path of Ruby executable file and the gem.bat in linux?

Tags: ruby, linux, centos, phpstorm

I need to set a path Variable on PHPStorm for the ruby executable file and the gem.bat.

I am using a virtual machine that has installed CentOS, and I just ran

```
$ sudo yum install ruby
```

Now I need to find the path, but I have no idea where ruby was installed under which directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `which` or `type` command:

```
$ which ruby
```

or

```
$ type ruby
```

It will show you the path of the executable if the directory contains the executable is listed in PATH.

Comment: it listed me /usr/bin/ruby. This will mean that the executable is inside bin?

Comment: @Monica, It means the `ruby` executable is in `/usr/bin` directory.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15845/which-and-find-not-working-to-locate-ruby-exe-path?newreg=90cc3a7497cf4307ba11e90917c5ca11 No `.bat` and `.exe` in Unix